# Swift optional addition using addition assignment (+=) operator

Tags: swift

I got the following piece of code from the Apple's developer documentation.

```
var testScores = ["Dave": [86, 82, 84], "Bev": [79, 94, 81]]
testScores["Bev"]?[0] += 1
```

It's working fine, but if I do it the following way, I am getting a compiler error.

```
testScores["Dave"]?[0] = testScores["Dave"]?[0] + 1
```

since `testScores["Dave"]?[0]` gives out an optional `Int` (i.e. `Int?`), I am expecting the code to trigger an error in both cases. What am I missing?

//edited in response to **codeDifferent**

If I have two classes as followed,

```
class Country {
var capitalCity: City?
}
class City{
var name : String?
}
```

var country = Country()

country.capitalcity?.name = "somevalue"

is safe, even if the capitalCity property is nil.

Comment: The documentation didn't explain this clearly. Optional chaining means "don't do anything after the `?` mark if the expression before it returns `nil`" You can write `testScores["Jack"]?[0] += 1` without any error at compile time or runtime. In the first example, by the time it reaches the `+=` operator, the compiler knows that it can't be `nil` so it can implicitly unwrap the `Optional<Int>` to `Int`

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. But, I guess the documentation says that it is safe to use something after the ? mark, even if the expression before it returns a nil. At least, I thought it was.

Comment: Safe? Yes, `country.capitalCity?.name = "somevalue"` won't crash. Is it right? Absolutely not. `country` still has a `nil` `capitalCity`. Nothing was written because there was no city to write to.

Comment: Why is `capitalCity` and `name` optional at all? In real life there is no country without a capital city and no city without a name. Don't use optional properties as an laziness alibi not to write an initializer.